# react warning: Functions are not valid as a React child with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs

I would like to click a remote button to print a pdf ( with the react-pdf library component: PDFDownloadLink ) , but sometimes it usually fails, and in the console I get this warning:

Functions are not valid as a React child

I have read other answers in this forum but I just can't see the bug in my code.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
 const pdfRef = useRef(null);
    
      // sessionStorage on window load event
      window.onload = () => {
        let reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
        if (reloading) {
          sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
          pdfRef.current.click();
        }
      }
      // Save a session on handlePDF call
      const handlePDF = () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
        window.location.reload(false);
      };


const PdfLinkButton = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <button style={{ display: "none" }} class="btn btn-primary  mb-5">
      <PDFDownloadLink
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#0A71F1", color: "white" }}
        document={<TestPDF />}
        fileName="Informe CMF.pdf"
      >
       
        <div ref={ref}>
          {({ loading }) => (loading ? "Loading" : "Download PDF ")}
        </div>
      </PDFDownloadLink>
    </button>
  ));


return (

<>
<button onClick={ handlePDF } class="btn btn-primary  mb-5">
                Download PDF
              </button>

<PdfLinkButton ref={ pdfRef } /> 

</>

)
```

Comment: `forwardRef` has nothing to do with it. You are using a function as a component child `{({ loading }) => (loading ? "Loading" : "Download PDF ")}`. Try doing `{loading ? "Loading" : "Download PDF "}`

Comment: Thank you but says 'loading' is not defined

Comment: Then define it ;). How else would it exist?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was able to solve it!